# How Can I Render The Contents Of My Database Using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I'm trying to render the components of my mongo database. I've tried res.send and it's working, but when I try to res.render it into the index.ejs file, it doesn't work. Console.logging is working but rendering isn't working. I think I'm missing something.

I've tried res.send(posts). Found posts already by sending a get request and defined like this in rendering res.render('index.ejs', {posts: foundPosts})
res.send(posts) is working and showing me my posts, but ejs is not working.
My EJS Code
Removed brackets due to problem in Stack Overflow. But these are present in original coding.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
post.find({}, function(err, posts){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render('index', {posts: posts});
    }
});
});
<h1><%= posts.title %></h1>
 <img src="<%= posts.url %>" alt="">
```

I expected to be all posts there, but it's showing a blank page.

Comment: how you are rendering your ejs file? is there any folder named view? have you set your view engine to ejs?

Comment: Yes, I've already done everything. My EJS File is being rendered without any errors. But, when I try to include my database contents in it, it returns blank.

Comment: then, your code looks fine to me. Does your server.js code contain `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`, `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))` those two lines of view middleware?
and when you console.log your data, the data's are from mongodb?

Comment: Yes, the datas are from mongodb that I created. I've set view engine to ejs. Please you try this code perosnally. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found what's the main issue here. You are returning a list of post from the database for this, you have to use a loop. Edit your **index.ejs** file like this:

```
<% posts.forEach(function(row){ %>
   <ul>
       <li> <%= row.title %> </li>
    </ul>
<% }) %>
```